How do I enable the function to insert blocks within blocks when registering ACF blocks?
I'm trying to create a wrapper block so that users can put multiple blocks inside the same wrapper instead of them each having their own wrapper.
My preference is to do this through PHP. I've been following a few guides online for enabling inner blocks on a block that has been registered with Advanced Custom Fields. I'm sure I've included everything that is required, yet I can't get the editor to allow me to insert the other block inside it.
[WP Gutenberg list view] (https://i.sstatic.net/WR7perwX.png)
What am I doing wrong?
My PHP for registering the blocks. I've included 'jsx' => true as I've seen that is a requirement.
<?php

/**
 * Create custom blocks here.
 */
function theme_blocks() {
  $blocks = [];

  $blocks[] = [
    'name' => 'general',
    'title' => 'General',
    'mode' => 'edit',
    'supports' => ['mode' => false, 'align' => false]
  ];

  $blocks[] = [
    'name' => 'page-section',
    'title' => 'Page Section',
    'mode' => 'edit',
    'supports' => ['jsx' => true, 'mode' => false, 'align' => false, 'anchor' => true]
  ];

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Loop through defined blocks from theme_blocks and register them.
 */
function theme_register_blocks() {
  foreach ( theme_blocks() as $block ) {
    $block['render_template'] = "template-parts/blocks/{$block['name']}.php";
    acf_register_block_type( $block );
  }
}

// Check if function exists and hook into setup.
if ( function_exists( 'acf_register_block_type' ) ) {
  add_action( 'acf/init', 'theme_register_blocks' );
}

The HTML for the page section
<div class="container">
  <InnerBlocks />
</div>

Not sure if it makes a difference, but here is my PHP/HTML for the other block, as well
<?php
/**
 * ACF General Block template.
 *
 * @param array $block The block settings and attributes
 * @param string $content Inner blocks content if jsx is enabled
 * @param boolean $is_preview True during preview render
 * @param array $context any context variables from parent blocks if applicable
 */

$fields = get_fields(); ?>

<div <?php block_id($block); ?>class="container<?php echo $fields['show_sidebar'] ? ' grid' : ''; ?>">

  <div class="cell col-lg-8">
    <?php 
      // Only add H2 HTML if there is a heading
      if( !empty($fields['heading']) ): ?>
        <h2><?php echo $fields['heading']; ?></h2><?php 
      endif; 

      echo $fields['content']; 
    ?>
  </div>
  <?php if ( $fields['show_sidebar'] ): ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <?php echo $fields['sidebar']['type']; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>


After some experimentation, I've answered my own question. By removing arguments one by one until it worked, I discovered that my "mode" argument is incorrect.
<?php
$blocks[] = [
  'name' => 'page-section',
  'title' => 'Page Section',
  'mode' => 'preview',
  'supports' => ['jsx' => true, 'mode' => false, 'align' => false, 'anchor' => true]
 ];

Mode needs to be preview for me to be able to drop blocks into my page section.
